# Airflow example_branch_operator usage of join - bug?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

As a newbie to airflow, I'm looking at the `example_branch_operator`:

```
"""Example DAG demonstrating the usage of the BranchPythonOperator."""

import random

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='example_branch_operator',
    default_args=args,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    tags=['example', 'example2'],
) as dag:

    run_this_first = DummyOperator(
        task_id='run_this_first',
    )

    options = ['branch_a', 'branch_b', 'branch_c', 'branch_d']

    branching = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branching',
        python_callable=lambda: random.choice(options),
    )
    run_this_first >> branching

    join = DummyOperator(
        task_id='join',
        trigger_rule='none_failed_or_skipped',
    )

    for option in options:
        t = DummyOperator(
            task_id=option,
        )

        dummy_follow = DummyOperator(
            task_id='follow_' + option,
        )

        branching >> t >> dummy_follow >> join
```

Looking at the `join` operator, I'd expect for it to collect all the branches, but instead it's just another task that happens at the end of each branch. If multiple branches are executed, `join` will run that many times.

(yes, yes, it should be idempotent, but that's not the point of the question)

[image]

Is this a bug, a poorly named task, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree view displays a complete branch from each DAG root node.  Multiple branches that converge on a single task will be shown multiple times but they will only be executed once.  Check out the Graph View of this DAG:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Josh Fell! This picture is kind of what I was expecting to find in the tree view for that example. where do you see this in the webserver?

Comment: Also, did you mean "The tree view displays a complete **task run** from..."?

Comment: @JoeyBaruch There is a "Graph View" option in the set of icons under "Links" on the far right of the main DAG page (hover over the icons to see what each one represents).  Or, if you click on a DAG name from that main page -- you'll be taken to the Tree View -- right next to where "Tree View" is highlighted you should see "Graph View".  Here is a very handy guide on getting to know the Airflow UI: [https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-ui](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-ui)

I meant to say a **complete branch**.  Edited the answer.  Thanks for catching that!